# How can I transform coordinate between two cameras using openCV?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I have two intel realsense cameras: Camera<sub>Left</sub> and Camera<sub>Right</sub> .I'm trying to find the rotation matrix and transformation vector between these two cameras, so I can transform coordinate system between two cameras.

**Here is what I have tried:**

1.I use cv.calibrateCamera() to get intrinsic matrix: **M<sub>left</sub>** and **M<sub>right</sub>**
2.I use cv.stereoCalibrate() to get the rotation matrix **R** and transformation vector **T**
3.I took two pictures in the same time, they are P<sub>left</sub> and P<sub>right</sub>. 
4.(u<sub>left</sub>, v<sub>left</sub>) and (u<sub>right</sub>, v<sub>right</sub>) indicating the same object in two pictures. Having the intrinsic matrix M<sub>left</sub> , M<sub>right</sub> ,and the depth D<sub>left</sub>, D<sub>right</sub>, and (u<sub>left</sub>, v<sub>left</sub>) , (u<sub>right</sub>, v<sub>right</sub>) , I get the camera coordinate (X<sub>left</sub>, Y<sub>left</sub>, Z<sub>left</sub>) and (X<sub>right</sub>, Y<sub>right</sub>, Z<sub>right</sub>).

**Here is the problem:**
In my assuming, **R***(X<sub>left</sub>, Y<sub>left</sub>, Z<sub>left</sub>) + **T** = (X<sub>right</sub>, Y<sub>right</sub>, Z<sub>right</sub>). But the result is not that.

here is my codes:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
import cv2


cameraMatLeft = np.array([
        [
            1286.540148375528,
            0.0,
            929.5596785987797
        ],
        [
            0.0,
            1272.8889372475517,
            586.0340979684613
        ],
        [
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0
        ]
    ]) 
cameraMatRight = np.array([
        [
            1294.8590822926074,
            0.0,
            976.7466553094133
        ],
        [
            0.0,
            1283.5006893318534,
            520.6437123281569
        ],
        [
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0
        ]
    ])

R = np.array([
        [
            0.736828762715704,
            0.1290536263233139,
            0.6636479005976342
        ],
        [
            -0.09833992557804119,
            0.9916309806151367,
            -0.08364961040894248
        ],
        [
            -0.6688891040166153,
            -0.0036276462155228617,
            0.7433533525254223
        ]
    ])

T = np.array([
        [
            -190.9527690494799
        ],
        [
            11.868938400892926
        ],
        [
            71.571368261639625
        ]
    ])





# two pixel point
rightPoint = (1107,568) 
leftPoint = (1840,697)


fLeft = h5py.File('C:\\SMIIP\\camera\\depth_pics\\leftDepth0.h5','r')
fRight = h5py.File('C:\\SMIIP\\camera\\depth_pics\\rightDepth0.h5','r')


d_left = fLeft['depth'][leftPoint[1], leftPoint[0]]
d_right = fRight['depth'][rightPoint[1], rightPoint[0]]

#print(d_left)
#print(d_right)

leftInv = np.linalg.inv(cameraMatLeft)
RightInv = np.linalg.inv(cameraMatRight)

leftPixPoint = np.array([d_left*leftPoint[0], d_left*leftPoint[1], d_left])
rightPixPoint = np.array([d_right*rightPoint[0], d_right*rightPoint[1], d_right])

#compute the camera coordinate
leftResult = np.matmul(leftInv, leftPixPoint)
rightResult = np.matmul(RightInv, rightPixPoint)
leftResult = leftResult.reshape(3, 1)
rightResult = rightResult.reshape(3, 1)

leftRotated = np.matmul(R, leftResult) + T
rightRotated = np.matmul(R, rightResult) + T

print(leftResult,rightResult)

#print(leftRotated, rightRotated)
```

Am I doing something wrong? Please help me out here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are doing is not completely wrong but I am not sure about the formula you are using in order to convert your left_cam coordinates to righ_cam coordinates.
From what I saw on this reference : [Here.](https://www.cse.unr.edu/%7Ebebis/CS791E/Notes/StereoCamera.pdf)

So from what they say Pr=R(Pl-T) .
Not sure this will solve your situation but hope I can be helpful.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I know the problem now. That my two cameras' plane are not parallel, so the result of cv.cv.stereoCalibrate()  is useless.